# How can one gurantees the intersection of two set is empty with respect to its hash value?

Tags: algorithms, hash-function

Let's say we have sets

- A = {1,2,3}
  and
- B = {1,3,10}

and our hash function is

- h(x) = 2x + 1(mod9)

therefore
H(A) = {3,5,7}
H(B) = {3,7}

Therefore if there is no intersection between the elements of H(A) and H(B) then can we say that the it is guaranteed that intersection of A and B is empty? If so, how can we show it?

Comment: Consider the preimage of $h$. BTW, $h$ in this example is not really a hash function, since it is a bijective function. Hashes are usually  not invertible.

Comment: @hardmath thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $H(A) \cap H(B)=\emptyset$ guarantees that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, i.e., that $A \cap B=\emptyset$.

*Proof*: If $a \in A \cap B$, then $h(a) \in H(A) \cap H(B)$, so $H(A) \cap H(B) \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Rebecca. Does it true for all hash functions? What happens if the hash function is h(x) = (x-2)(x-1)? In that case both 1 and 2 maps to 0. Does it make any difference?

Comment: The property "$H(A) \cap H(B) = \emptyset$ implies $A \cap B = \emptyset$" is true regardless of the choice of hash function (the proof remains the same).  The trick is to choose a hash function that is (a) fast to compute and (b) will often result in situations where $H(A) \cap H(B)$.